# I used to know a Belgian guy who would say "Hoy!" exactly the same way Filipinos do. Is there some kind of historical connection or just coincidence?

Tags: etymology, cognates, tagalog

He was French Belgian. Is that a word they commonly say, or was he just a weirdo? If the former, are these Belgians somehow using the same etymologically identical "hoy" as Filipinos? How did the word transmit between them? Or is it just a case of "convergent evolution"?

(As I type this out it also occurs to me that he could've just grown up with a Filipino nanny.)

Comment: [Wiktionary says](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hoi#Dutch) its use as a greeting is only known from the 20th century, so it seems unlikely there should be any connection, beyond the fact that there are exclamations in lots of languages which are used for greeting or attracting attention and have the shape _hV(w/y)_: English _hi/hey/ahoy_, Dutch _(a)hoi_, Scandinavian _hei/hej_, Filipino _hoy_, Mandarin 嘿 _hēi_, Japanese はい _hai_ (also ‘yes’), Lakota/various Siouan (now ‘generic Native American’ in English) [_how_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_(greeting)), etc.

Comment: This sounds like it could be the English: Oy or Oi for Hey.  Not hoy with an h that looks Spanish.